# How to interpret HTML tags in attributes in XSL transformations?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

I've an existing functional transformation, that converts data XML files to nice and shiny HTML documents.

Now I want to highlight some of data under special conditions. My first idea was to use some HTML tags.
It works to a degree.

The first important step is to enable HTML interpretation after the transformation in the XSLT file.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

The problem, I believe, lies with the data. While text in tags can be expressed with CDATA ...

```
<title><![CDATA[<b>Title</b>]]></title>
```

... and works, data in attributes are much more doifficult to handle. First, CDATA can't work in attributes. So I tried HTML encoing.

```
&lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;
```

But this won't interpret, it shows the HTML tags witzh or without the disable-output-escaping="yes" in the transformation. I asume the decoding of the tags is to late to interpret.

Any ideas? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you please show a simple test case? A test case is an example input document, and the expected output document. Also, what version of XSLT? 1.0?, 2? or 3?

Comment: As Sean said, but if you have trouble setting it up, have a look at SO's [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> The problem, I believe, lies with the data. While text in tags can be expressed with CDATA ...
>
> ```
> <title><![CDATA[<b>Title</b>]]></title>
> ```

Perhaps the problem lies in the fact that you are trying to represent XML as text inside what is already XML, why not simply `<title><b>title</b></title>`? You'll get XML well-formedness check for free, and if you want to *do* something with the elements inside `<title>`, you can process them with your XSLT (which currently sees it as text, so you are very limited in what you can do with it).

> .. and works, data in attributes are much more doifficult to handle. First, CDATA can't work in attributes. So I tried HTML encoing.
>
> ```
> &lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;
> ```

Ouch, are you saying you are putting XML as text inside attributes? If you can prevent this... you'll save yourself loads of trouble. Attributes in XML contain flat values, not structured content.

> But this won't interpret, it shows the HTML tags witzh or without the disable-output-escaping="yes" in the transformation. I asume the decoding of the tags is to late to interpret.

*I don't think you mean "it shows ... in the transformation", as a transformation does not show anything. Do you mean how it shows when opened as HTML in a browser?*

No, the decoding it not too late to interpret. `disable-output-escaping` only has effect on text inside elements. Not on element names, not on attribute names or values. This was probably a design choice back in the days of XSLT 1.0 (almost 20 years ago!), but it makes sense, as otherwise it is yet another invitation to create invalid XML.

> Any ideas? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Yes. If at all possible (I don't know the extend of your situation and sometimes history shows that we have to live with design choices from the past), do not store XML or HTML as text (what you call `CDATA`) inside tags, let alone inside attributes.

If you cannot help this, then upon transformation, transform the attributes into text inside elements and your `disable-output-escaping` will work again. But either way, the solution will be ugly at best.

---

As an aside: if you use server-side processing and you are stuck with a system that stores XML this way, you can perhaps switch to XSLT 3.0, which has a function `parse-xml()` as part of XPath 3.0 which can take a string like the ones you have an interpret it as XML. This way you can validate it and process it somehow.

However, not even XSLT 3.0 allows you to write tags inside attribute values.